# How to return alphabetically my map function with React?

Tags: reactjs, react-hooks

I have a JSON file :

```
[
  {
    "level_1": "music",
    "level_2": "rock",
    "level_3": "had-rock / metal"
  },
  {
    "level_1": "music",
    "level_2": "rap",
    "level_3": "rapcore / rap-west-coast"
  },
  {
    "level_1": "music",
    "level_2": "country",
    "level_3": "contry-rock / country-pop"
  }
]
```

I want render a select, for this I call my json file:

```
const [musicType, setMusicType] = useState([]);

useEffect(() => {
    axios
        .get("https://www.musictype")
        .then(function (response) {
            setMusicType(response.data);
        })
        .catch(function (error) {
    console.log('request failed', error)
  })
}, []);
```

And i create a map function on the return :

```
<select>
  <option value="" placeholder="Selection">Selection</option>
  {musicType.map((type, index) => (
  <option key={index}>{type.level_3}</option>))}
</select>
```

But it isn't render alphabetically, if I Use sort()  React display an error:

```
<select>
  <option value="" placeholder="Selection">Selection</option>
  {musicType.sort((a,b) => (
  <option key={index}>{a.level_3.localeCompare(b.level_3)}</option>))}
</select>
```

"Error: valid as a React child (found: object with keys {level_1, level_2, level_3}). If you meant to render a collection of children, use an array instead."

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Sort array of objects by string property value](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1129216/sort-array-of-objects-by-string-property-value)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Compare function passed to sort method should follow the [doc](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/sort) which return `0 or 1 or -1` defining the order

So here you should sort it separately and then map for elements to be rendered afterward

```
<select>
  <option value="" placeholder="Selection">Selection</option>
  {musicType
     .sort((a,b) => a.level_3.localeCompare(b.level_3))
     .map((type, index) => (
       <option key={index}>{type.level_3}</option>
     ))
  }
</select>
```

Answer (score 0):

First `sort` then `map` to a single string. Try this,

```
            <select>
                <option value="" placeholder="Selection">
                    Selection
                </option>
                {musicType
                    .sort((a, b) => {
                        a = a.level_3.toLowerCase();
                        b = b.level_3.toLowerCase();
                        return a < b ? -1 : a > b ? 1 : 0;
                    })
                    .map((type, index) => (
                        <option key={index}>{type.level_3}</option>
                    ))}
            </select>
```

NOTE: You can sort by any property of the `JSON`. Just change `a.level_1` and `b.level_1` instead of the `level_3`.

Comment: Uncaught TypeError: a.level_3.toLowercase is not a function

Comment: @gcbox999, it is `toLowerCase` not `toLowercase`. C is capital